# handling a geohash dict look up with spatial joins

Tags: python, geospatial, geohashing

I have a dictionary with geohash as keys and a value associated with them. I am looking up values from the dict to create a new column in my pandas dataframe.

```
geo_dict = {'9q5dx': 10, '9q9hv': 15, '9q5dv': 20}


df = pd.DataFrame({'geohash': ['9q5dx','9qh0g','9q9hv','9q5dv'],
                   'label': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})


df['value'] = df.apply(lambda x : geo_dict[x.geohash], axis=1)
```

I need to be able to handle non-matches, i.e geohashes that do not exist in the dictionary. Expected handling below:

- Find k-number of geohashes nearby and compute the mean value
- Assign the mean of neighboring geohashes to pandas column

Questions -

Is there a library I can use to find nearby geohashes?
How do I code up this solution?

Comment: What do you want to do? Take the mean of geohashes within a certain radius that exist in the dict? Or take the mean of the closest n geohashes in the dict?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen the latter. Take the mean of n neighboring geohashes in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

The module [pygeodesy](https://github.com/mrJean1/PyGeodesy) has [several functions](https://github.com/mrJean1/PyGeodesy/blob/master/pygeodesy/geohash.py) to calculate distance between geohashes. We can wrap this in a function that first checks is a match exists in the dict, else returns the mean value of the n closest geohashes:

```
import pygeodesy as pgd 
import pandas as pd

geo_dict = {'9q5dx': 10, '9q9hv': 15, '9q5dv': 20}
geo_df = pd.DataFrame(zip(geo_dict.keys(), geo_dict.values()), columns=['geohash', 'value'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'geohash': ['9q5dx','9qh0g','9q9hv','9q5dv'],
                   'label': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})

def approximate_distance(geohash1, geohash2):
    return pgd.geohash.distance_(geohash1, geohash2)
    #return pgd.geohash.equirectangular_(geohash1, geohash2) #alternative ways to calculate distance
    #return pgd.geohash.haversine_(geohash1, geohash2)

def get_value(x, n=2): #set number of closest geohashes to use for approximation with n
    val = geo_df.loc[geo_df['geohash'] == x]
    if not val.empty:
        return val['value'].iloc[0]
    else:
        geo_df['tmp_dist'] = geo_df['geohash'].apply(lambda y: approximate_distance(y,x))
        return geo_df.nlargest(n, 'tmp_dist')['value'].mean()

df['value'] = df['geohash'].apply(get_value)
```

result:

|  | geohash | label | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 9q5dx | a | 10 |
| 1 | 9qh0g | b | 12.5 |
| 2 | 9q9hv | c | 15 |
| 3 | 9q5dv | d | 20 |